# What could cause the Nikon D7500 display to look like a cartoon/colour blocking?

Tags: nikon, display

All of a sudden the display on my Nikon D7500 is showing photos in a "cartoonish" and colour blocking - the pictures are OK when I see them on my computer or my phone, but I can of course not see them and check them properly as I’m shooting. Can this be fixed? Is it a setting? Or do I have to bring the camera in for service?

[image]

Answer (score 11):

It's hard to diagnose without a picture of the problem, but one possibility comes to mind. Make sure that you don't have the "Photo Illustration" special effect turned on (p 64 in the manual). This effect will be shown in the EVF but if you have both NEF and JPG enabled the NEF may not show the effect.

Comment: (Just in case you're not watching, the question has now been updated with an image)

Comment: Thank you. Have checked them. Can’t find the Photo Illustrator option anywhere though. Thanks for taking the time. Lisa

Answer (score 1):

A few things could cause the display on your Nikon D7500 to look like a cartoon/color blocking.

- The Photo Illustration special effect is turned on. This effect can be found in the camera's menu system. If it is turned on, it will cause the display to show photos in a cartoonish style. To turn off this effect, go to the Photo Shooting Menu > Image Effects > Photo Illustration and set it to Off.
- The camera's color space is set to something other than sRGB. The sRGB color space is the default color space for the Nikon D7500. If the camera's color space is set to something else, such as Adobe RGB, the display may show photos differently than on a computer or phone. To change the camera's color space, go to the Photo Shooting Menu > Image Quality > Color Space and select sRGB.
- The camera's display is damaged. Photos may be distorted or incorrect if the camera's display is damaged. If you think the camera's display is damaged, you should bring it in for service.

**To troubleshoot the issue, you can try the following:**

- Turn off the Photo Illustration special effect.
- Change the camera's color space to sRGB.
- Reset the camera to its factory settings. This will erase all your custom settings but may fix the issue.

If you have tried all these things and the issue is still there, you may need to bring the camera in for service.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be 100% sure but:

- evidently, display uses all pixels to display image
- there's no non-uniform noise
- there's no evidence of damage

what follows me to the conclusion that it's camera software bug. You definitely need to have it serviced since the pictures look fine out of the camera.